# More problems with arrays, methods, and ref parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, ref

Earlier today I was working on my homework for my C# class [LINK TO PREVIOUS PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313320/need-help-using-ref-and-arrays-and-methods) and now I have another problem which I am not understanding what is wrong. So with the first post I had a problem with static parameters so I got that explained and fixed. But now, I'm getting an error saying than an "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I checked for any typos and still can not run it. PS, problem appears not when compiling, but rather when all data is entered and when I press N after typing in the data and hitting enter. Please take a look.

```
using System;

public class Repository 
{
    static string[] titles;
    static string[] authorFirstNames;
    static string[] authorLastNames;
    static string[] publisherNames;
    static float[] prices;
    static int number;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string title = "";
        string authorFirst = "";
        string authorLast = "";
        string publisherName = "";
        float price = 0;

        getBookInfo(ref title, ref authorFirst, ref authorLast, ref publisherName, ref price);      
        displayBooks(titles, authorFirstNames, authorLastNames, publisherNames, prices, number);
    }

    static void getBookInfo(ref string title, ref string authorFirst, 
                            ref string authorLast, ref string publisherName, 
                            ref float price)
    {
        string continued;
        string float_num;
        int i = 0;

        titles = new string[50];

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Title of book: ");
            title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Authors first name: ");
            authorFirst = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Authors last name: ");
            authorLast = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Publishers Name: ");
            publisherName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Price: ");
            float_num = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Add another book? Y/N ");
            continued = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            price = float.Parse(float_num);

            titles[i] = title;
            authorFirstNames[i] = authorFirst;
            authorLastNames[i] = authorLast;
            publisherNames[i] = publisherName;
            prices[i] = price;

            number = i;

            i++;
        }
        while (continued == "y");
    }

    static void displayBooks(string[] titles, string[] authorFirstNames, 
                             string[] authorLastNames, string[] publisherNames, 
                             float[] prices, int number)
    {
        foreach (string title in titles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            if(title == null)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the cause?

Regards, and hope for some advice.

PS, displayBooks method isn't finished yet.

Comment: What line do you get the exception at?

Comment: Make sure to tag your homework questions with the homework tag. Then people know to help you as opposed to just telling the answer =)

Comment: It is line 52, and I will add another tag next time, thanks.

Comment: When are you initializing any of the arrays (besides titles)?

Comment: Ahaa! There's my problem! I need to add initializers right under  line 32. Good eye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line `static string[] authorFirstNames;`

You're not initializing your array, so the object is null. You need to initialize it like this: `static string[] authorFirstNames=new string[1];` You have to specify the size of the array, which is what the [1] is. It means the array can hold 1 string.

You can use Array.Resize() to resize the array at a later point.

If the project permits it, you may want to use a `List<string>` instead of an array of strings.

You can figure this sort of thing out on your own by looking at the code in a debugger. In this case, assuming you're using Visual Studio, it highlights the line where the exception is thrown. If you look at the value of `authorFirstNames`, you see it's null, which means it was never initialized.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at this right now, and no, I'm using MonoDevelop. Trying to stay out of Micro$oft.

Comment: You're using MonoDevelop purely because you don't like Microsoft - even when there's a free version of Visual Studio.. and yet you're using C#?

Comment: @Rob: It's possible that he's forced to use C#(as in, the course at his school/college is taught using C#), so he preferred mono as a way of staying as far as HE could from Microsoft =) 
Same tough luck follows me in my university :(

Comment: @Abel Even so, deliberatly going out of your way to use an inferior (Don't get me wrong, Mono is incredible, but it's not _perfect_) product purely out of spite is a bit counter-productive. It's like buying a Mac and running every single application under WINE just to avoid microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any place in your code initialize these variable:

```
static string[] authorFirstNames;
static string[] authorLastNames;
static string[] publisherNames;
static float[] prices;
```